# MySQL full-text search: "proves" gets "proves" but not "prove"

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

Please show me where I'm wrong with this query:

```
SELECT * FROM `pages` WHERE MATCH ( abstrak) AGAINST ('+"prove"' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

doesn't get '*proves*', when I want is it gets 'proves'.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM `pages` WHERE MATCH ( abstrak) AGAINST ('prove*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

This would match all words that start with `prove`, including `proves`.

More info at:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/fulltext-boolean.html

Comment: It necessary the _matching_ word(s) is in quotes because it could be more than one word.

Comment: `A phrase that is enclosed within double quote (“"”) characters matches only rows that contain the phrase literally, as it was typed. The full-text engine splits the phrase into words and performs a search in the FULLTEXT index for the words. Nonword characters need not be matched exactly: Phrase searching requires only that matches contain exactly the same words as the phrase and in the same order. For example, "test phrase" matches "test, phrase". `

Comment: Yes, that's what I intend to. If a visitor needs to 'prove' I need that 'prove' or 'proves' the visitor gets. But if he/she search for 'prove nothing' I need only the row match with 'prove nothing' and not for example 'proves nothing'.
Hope you understand that, sorry for my English.